# Customising project debugging in Visual Studio project flavor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsx, extensibility, vsip

I am extending Visual Studios project system, using C# (MPF). I have written a custom 'project flavor', by extending 'FlavoredProjectBase' - and I have 'flavored' the C# Class Library project.
I want my project type to support F5 debugging, with the project configured to 'Start Project' (I could use 'start external program', but I dont want that).
How do I customise what happens when the user presses F5?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might need to look at the following interface [IVsDebuggableProjectCfg2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsdebuggableprojectcfg2.aspx)

Visit [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/d7e33555-0b5b-4f48-8c07-3fc78e0ff6cf) for the complete issue.